# Alternative derivation of $P(\text{First qubit}=0)$ for the swap test

Tags: mathematics

I'm trying to derive $P(\text{First qubit}=0) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}|⟨a|b⟩|^2$ for the [swap test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test).

[image]

The wiki page shows one way, but the result should also be obtainable via direct expansion of the tensor products, as attempted [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12348/12643). Present question is about bringing this process to completion as I — rather disappointingly — wasn't able to finish the proof myself.

To summarize the thought process (adapted from [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12350/12643)), let's assume we start out with:

$$
|a \rangle = a_0 |0\rangle + a_1 |1\rangle \\
|b \rangle = b_0 |0\rangle + b_1 |1\rangle \\
|\phi_0 \rangle = |0 \rangle |a \rangle |b \rangle
$$

Applying $H$ to $|\phi_0\rangle$, we get:

$$
|\phi_1 \rangle = H|0\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle
$$

Applying the swap, we get:

$$
|\phi_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle|b\rangle|a\rangle
$$

Applying the second H, we get:

$$
|\phi_3 \rangle = H|\phi_2\rangle = \\
\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle|a\rangle|b\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle|b\rangle|a\rangle - \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle|b\rangle|a\rangle =
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \left[|a\rangle|b\rangle + |b\rangle|a\rangle\right] + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \left[|a\rangle|b\rangle - |b\rangle|a\rangle \right] \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

If we want to calculate $P(\text{First qubit}=0)$, then the interesting quantity from $|\phi_3\rangle$ is the first term of \eqref{1}:

$$
\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \left[|a\rangle|b\rangle + |b\rangle|a\rangle\right]
= \\
\frac{1}{2} \left[
2 a_0 b_0 |0,0\rangle
+ \left( a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 \right) |0,1\rangle
+ \left( a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 \right) |1,0\rangle
+ 2 a_1 b_1 |1,1\rangle
\right] =
$$
$$
a_0 b_0 |0,0\rangle
+ \frac{1}{2} \left( a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 \right) |0,1\rangle
+ \frac{1}{2} \left( a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 \right) |1,0\rangle
+ a_1 b_1 |1,1\rangle \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Where I used:
$$
|a \rangle |b \rangle =
a_0 b_0 |0,0\rangle
+ a_0 b_1 |0,1\rangle
+ a_1 b_0 |1,0\rangle
+ a_1 b_1 |1,1\rangle
\\
|b \rangle |a \rangle =
a_0 b_0 |0,0\rangle
+ a_1 b_0 |0,1\rangle
+ a_0 b_1 |1,0\rangle
+ a_1 b_1 |1,1\rangle
$$

Squaring the amplitudes from \eqref{2}, we get:

$$
|a_0 b_0|^2
+ \frac{1}{4} | a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 |^2
+ \frac{1}{4} | a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 |^2
+ |a_1 b_1|^2 =
$$
$$
|a_0 b_0|^2
+ \frac{1}{2} | a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 |^2
+ |a_1 b_1|^2 \tag{3}\label{3}
$$

I'm trying to prove that \eqref{3} equals $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}|⟨a|b⟩|^2$ but I could not.
I tried using:

**EDIT: The following equations do not hold, as explained by C. Kang in the answers.**

$$
|\langle a| b \rangle|^2 =
\langle a| b \rangle\langle a| b \rangle^\dagger =
\langle a| b \rangle\langle b| a \rangle =
\langle b| \langle a| b \rangle |a\rangle =
|a_0 b_0|^2 + |a_1 b_0|^2 + |a_0 b_1|^2 + |a_1 b_1|^2
$$
$$
|a_0 b_0|^2 + |a_1 b_1|^2 = |\langle a| b \rangle|^2 - |a_1 b_0|^2 - |a_0 b_1|^2 \tag{4}\label{4}
$$

Substituting \eqref{4} into \eqref{3}, I got:

$$
|\langle a| b \rangle|^2 - |a_1 b_0|^2 - |a_0 b_1|^2 + \frac{1}{2} | a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 |^2
$$

But I'm not sure how to turn this into $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}|⟨a|b⟩|^2$. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community Attila! I do not believe your equation 4 holds; consider the orthogonal vectors $ [\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}]^T, [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]^T$ - their inner product should be 0 by orthogonality, but it can been seen that each of the terms you have would be nonzero, so their sum must be nonzero.

The correct expansion for (4) would be:
$$ | \langle a | b \rangle |^2 = | \overline{a_0}b_0 + \overline{a_1}b_1 |^2 = (\overline{a_0} b_0 + \overline{a_1} b_1) \overline{(\overline{a_0}b_0 + \overline{a_1}b_1)} $$

Which, by distributivity of complex conjugation simplifies to:

$$ (\overline{a_0}b_0 + \overline{a_1}b_1)(a_0\overline{b_0} + a_1\overline{b_1}) = |a_0b_0|^2 + |a_1b_1|^2 + \overline{a_1 b_0} a_0 b_1 + \overline{a_0 b_1}a_1 b_0 $$

Let's also rewrite (3). Again, we can use the trick for the norm squared:

$$ |a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0 |^2 = (a_0 b_1 + a_1 b_0)(\overline{a_0 b_1} + \overline{a_1 b_0}) = |a_0 b_1|^2 + |a_1 b_0|^2 + a_0 b_1 \overline{a_1 b_0} + a_1 b_0 \overline{a_0 b_1}$$

So, the entire (3) is:

$$ \frac{1}{2} (2|a_0 b_0|^2 + 2 |a_1 b_1|^2 + |a_0 b_1|^2 + |a_1 b_0|^2 + a_0 b_1 \overline{a_1 b_0} + a_1 b_0 \overline{a_0 b_1}) = \frac{1}{2}( |a_0 b_0|^2 + |a_0 b_1|^2 + |a_1 b_0|^2 + |a_1 b_1|^2 + |\langle a | b \rangle |^2)$$

Finally, recognize that $ |a_0 b_0|^2 + |a_0 b_1|^2 + |a_1 b_0|^2 + |a_1 b_1|^2 $ is actually just 1! (As it's the amplitudes of $|a \rangle |b \rangle$). Thus, we yield:

$$ \frac{1}{2} (1 + | \langle a| b \rangle |^2 )$$

As desired!

Comment: Thanks, indeed (4) seems wrong as shown by your counterexample. I'm still not quite sure where the illegal step is made though: 
$|\langle a| b \rangle|^2 =
\langle b| \langle a| b \rangle |a\rangle
$ holds, right?
$$$$
If the answer is yes, then I can use 
$
|b \rangle |a \rangle =
a_0 b_0 |0,0\rangle
+ a_1 b_0 |0,1\rangle
+ a_0 b_1 |1,0\rangle
+ a_1 b_1 |1,1\rangle
$
to calculate
$
\langle b| \langle a| =
\overline{a_0 b_0} \langle 0,0|
+ \overline{a_1 b_0} \langle 0,1|
+ \overline{a_0 b_1} \langle 1,0|
+ \overline{a_1 b_1} \langle 1,1|
$

(continued)

Comment: Calculating the product $\left( \langle b| \langle a| \right) \left( | b \rangle |a \rangle \right)$ yields my incorrect (4) but I'm not sure where the illegal step is?

Comment: Hm, I think that the $ \langle b | \langle a | b \rangle | a \rangle  = \langle b | a \rangle (\overline{a_0} b_0 + \overline{a_1} b_1) = (\overline{b_0} a_0 + \overline{b_1} a_1)(\overline{a_0} b_0 + \overline{a_1} b_1) $. Then, this quantity simplifies to $ |a_0 b_0|^2 + |a_1 b_1|^2 + a_0 b_1 \overline {a_1 b_0} + a_1 b_0 \overline{a_0 b_1} $

Comment: I agree that's what you get from $\langle b | \left( \langle a | b \rangle \right) | a \rangle$ by calculating the middle term first. But I thought bra-kets are associative so:
$\left( \langle b| \otimes \langle a| \right) \left( | b \rangle | \otimes |a \rangle \right) =
\left( \overline{a_0 b_0} \langle 0,0| + \overline{a_1 b_0} \langle 0,1| + \overline{a_0 b_1} \langle 1,0| + \overline{a_1 b_1} \langle 1,1| \right)
\left( a_0 b_0 |0,0\rangle + a_1 b_0 |0,1\rangle + a_0 b_1 |1,0\rangle + a_1 b_1 |1,1\rangle \right)=
|a_0 b_0|^2 + |a_1 b_0|^2 + |a_0 b_1|^2 + |a_1 b_1|^2$. Which is wrong.

Comment: Ooh, good q, I think it could be because $\langle 0, 1 | 1, 0 \rangle = 1$ (vs \langle 0, 1 | 0, 1 \rangle = 0$), which gives the desired coefficients

Comment: Thanks, I can see my mistake now. Something else bothers me though: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12348/12643
This answer deals with the same topic but in equation 2B arrives at a different result for the case of the first qubit being 0. In the comments there I tried to explain why I think it's wrong but I didn't get a response. Would you agree with that reasoning?
I apologize if this is a bit off-topic.

Comment: I skimmed the other prompt, but I believe you are correct except for needing to square the amplitudes. Besides that, though, you correctly consolidate like terms

Comment: Thanks for your time. I made the edit.